# Is Azure OAuth 2 auth code grant an authentication protocol

Tags: azure-active-directory

Sorry I am still very confused, read everywhere telling me oath is a authorisation protocol but it appears using the azure ad oauth code grant, it does promote a login screen to authenticate against the directory, so is it not an authentication process? what is the relationship between the open id connect? thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the OAuth2.0 protocol has several flows that an identity provider (in your case Azure AD) may implement to support auth.

The Auth Code flow is in fact one of these used by apps to get access tokens for some api.  The flow is quite simple, an app redirects the user to the identity providers `/authorize` endpoint. At this point the user enters their credentials, and the site redirects back to your application with an ***authorization code*** and can also issue an `ID Token` that represents a user (This is the OpenID Connect part).  The app takes this code, and POSTs it to the `/token` endpoint and will be issued an `access token` and `refresh token`.  With the `access token`, your app can access whatever api you've requested access for.

For Azure AD specifically, Microsoft has built libraries that handle all these flows and token caching so most of the complexity is abstracted away.  There's some simple [code samples](https://aka.ms/aaddev) that you can checkout that you may find helpful. The [authentication protocols and scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios) doc for Azure AD may also be really helpful for conceptual information.

Comment: Thanks, however After decode the access token I did not see the idtoken claim, also the vendor is asking to go v2 endpoint, what is th difference with the v1 really, for the use case of web API

Comment: The id token is not a claim in the access token, it's another token issued by Azure AD. The v2 converged endpoint combines Azure AD and Microsoft Accounts (live, outlook, hotmail, etc).  You can read more about [the v2 endpoint](https://aka.ms/aadv2) which also has a lot of info on the differences.